# ObservableCollection - cannot implement because it does not have matching return type

Tags: .net, compiler-errors

I have two projects. 
First one is Wpf Project (FrameWork 3.5) with next interface:

```
public interface View
{
    ObservableCollection<int> Items { set; }  
}
```

and the test project (FrameWork 4.0)

```
public class ViewFake:View
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items
    {
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> ViewFake' does not implement interface member 'View.Items'.
>   'ViewFake.Items' cannot implement 'View.Items' because it does not
>   have the matching return type of
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1'.

I've looked where ObservableCollection is located in both versions, and

- [[FrameWork 4.0] - System.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [[FrameWork 3.5] - WindowsBase.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

So, the only solution is to upgrade the main project or to downgrade the test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If I'm not mistaken, ObservableCollection was in the System.Windows.* namespace in .NET 3.5, and only in 4.0 was it moved to the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace.</s>

*update: it wasn't the namespace that changed, but the assembly. Result is the same, however: .NET considers it a different type because the containing assembly is part of the type information.

The bigger problem here is that your tests and your classes under test are using different .NET framework versions and different versions of the Common Language Runtime. That will likely end in tears. Can you use the same version for your projects?

Comment: you are wrong about namespaces. It's equal in both frameworks. Difference is in dll as I said above, here it can bee seen: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx. About same framework - I'll have to persuade the author of the project. Different frameworks were used for a year and only now we came to a problem.

Comment: Oh - duh, it was the assembly that changed, not the namespace. Same result: the types are different.